# Remove char before specific string

Tags: bash

I have used the `find` command to get the following list of sub-folders:

```
$ find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type d
./aa/one
./bb/two
./cc/three
```

How can I remove `./**/`?

Expected result:

```
one
two
three
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo "./aa/one
./bb/two
./cc/three" | sed 's@^.*/@@'
one
two
three
```

or better use this instead:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type d -printf "%f\n"
```

Comment: thanks for the help !

Comment: @Luca since you're new here, don't forget to mark the answer accepted whenever it helped (most) in understanding and solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)